# Can I impersonate EF with Azure AD connected user?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am working on a Core 2 web app and I need to access the internal SQL Server with the user that has been logged in through the Azure AD Connect (SSO). I am trying to impersonate the user using Identity but does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**Provision an Azure Active Directory administrator for your Azure SQL Database server**

On Azure portal select SQL Server page and select `Active Directory admin`.In the `Active Directory admin` page, select `Set admin`.

[image]

In the Add admin page, search for a user, select the user or group to be an administrator, and then select `Save`.

To connect to a database using `integrated authentication` and an Azure AD identity, the Authentication keyword must be set to `Active Directory Password`. The connection string must contain User ID/UID and Password/PWD keywords and values. The following C# code sample uses ADO .NET.

```
<add name="SchoolContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="
Data Source=xxxxx.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Password; Initial Catalog=testdb;  UID=youradusername; PWD=MyPassWord"/>
```

After logining the Azure Sql server with Azure AD user name and password, then you could do operations with sql. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#connect-to-the-user-database-or-data-warehouse-by-using-ssms-or-ssdt).